# On my virtual emulator app works fine,but when generate apk file dont work well - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, android-install-apk, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to make some small app on Flutter(learning flutter).I have problem when install apk file on my phone.I make 2 app ,one with some images files,and second is fetch data(GET method) and put in simple list.Both of this my app works fine on emulator,but when i generate apk file(Build->Flutter->Build APK),(for security i see that is have 2 apk file ,and i try with each of this,one is in folder outputs->apk,and second is outputs->flutter-apk),i take this file apk on my real mobile device and install,when i start app doesnt see nothing just white screen on app with images,and second app is see appBar blue and header,and rest is white...I dont have any idea what could be?

Comment: Have you followed [this guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)?

Comment: I use this video tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SswHhcYEQ1U), from quide you post i see that need to sign if i want to generate apk from google play,but i want only for me apk,i dont sign just i go build->Flutter->Build APK